¿cómo hago para que mi archivo index.php se muestre al dar clic a un botón en una ventana modal?
====Tengo esta app para chatear pero quiero que al ponerlo en mi index.html poder abrirlo desde un botón en una ventana modal. Ahora si lo pongo en el index.html me abre en otra ventana y no quiero que haga eso.
De antemano muchas gracias y no sé si me he explicado bien.======
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
    header("location: users.php");
  }
?>

<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Hola amigos el problema que tengo es el siguiente. Tengo una app de chat creada totalmente en php. (no la he diseñado yo) y quiero que esa app funciones desde un botón en mi web creada en html. Que no se me abra en una pagina aparte sino que sea una especia de chatbox más o menos. No sé si logro explicarme.

¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

he intentado llamar la app desde mi index.html con un botón y me abre en otra ventana. Y lo que quiero es que se abra estilo chatbox; es decir en la misma ventana de la web y poder atender a los que se conecten al chat, sin tener que estar en una pagina y otra.







 === desde este icono quiero que se abra mi app, es decir index.php ===
Hola muchas gracias por responder. ya lo conseguí era muy fácil lo que pasaba era que yo estaba muy espeso en la mente.. Esta página me ha ayudado en muchas cosas. Nuevamente muchas gracias a tod@s.

@jorgeluis responde tu pregunta para saber como lo solucionaste

esta fue la solución... 







  </div>


@jorgeluis escribela en la parte de abajo, ordenando el código y explicando el error existente. No lo dejes en los comentarios.

Estás abriendo múltiples preguntas para el mismo problema. En lugar de crear muchas preguntas con pequeños fragmentos de código que son insuficientes para ayudarte por si solos, deberías editar una de las preguntas y añadir todos los datos y código para que tengan más sentido y se pueda ayudarte. Lee [ask] y sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Lo he intentado en verdad de hacerlo mejor. Pero no sé ni cómo preguntar en este chat. He escrito el código y lo que quiero conseguir pero cuando lo quiero enviar me da error. Perdón por ser tan neófito en este asunto
